# Switching Pictures in Paypal Form?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I seem to be having a problem with my paypal form but im sure there is a simple solutions (involving js) basically I have a simple paypal form with a slider image next to it (see code below)

```
  <div class="bg about" id="4">
            <a name="#shop"></a>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row marg75">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="promo-white">Choose from our fabulous collection</div>
                            <div class="promo-p" style="color:#fff;">With a range of variations</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 marg50">
                            <section class="slider">
                                <div class="flexslider">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <li><img src="assets/images/about-2.jpg" /></li>
                                        <li><img src="assets/images/about-1.jpg" /></li>
                                        <li><img src="assets/images/about-3.jpg" /></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 marg50">
                            <div class="about-block">
                                <div class="about-name" style="color:#fff;">Product Information</div>
                                <div class="about-text">
                                   <p style="color:#fff;">General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here. General  Product Information here.<br>
                                   </p>
                                   <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybiz.co.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="T-Shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size"></td>
    <td>
    <select name="os0">
    <option value="Select a Size">Select a colour
    <option value="RED">RED
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE
    <option value="BLACK">BLACK
    <option value="PINK">PINK

    </select></td>
    <td>
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

                      </div>
```

This part is fine however I wish the slider images to change depending on what dropdown colour is selected from the drop down menu (ie Blue is selected only blue images how) I have had a look around and tried a few ways however the js seems to stop working when incorporated with the paypal form? Anyone have a quick fix solution? Im sure there must be an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: I still cant seem to load the paypal and js script?